# Create a list of keys given a value in a dictionary

Tags: python

I have a dictionary that looks like this:

```
child_parent={}
child_parent[1]=0
child_parent[2]=0
child_parent[3]=2
child_parent[4]=2
```

If given 0 how can I find all keys into a list where the value is 0 that is pythonic?

end result of 0 is [1,2] and for 2 [3,4]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a list comprehension over the dict's `items`:

```
[k for k, v in child_parent.items() if v == 0]
```

```
>>> [k for k, v in child_parent.items() if v == 0]
 [1, 2]

>>> [k for k, v in child_parent.items() if v == 2]
 [3, 4]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
In [62]: [k for k,v in child_parent.iteritems() if v==0]
Out[62]: [1, 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def find_keys(d, x):
  return [key for key in d if d[key] == x]
```

This iterates over each key in the dictionary `d` and creates a list out of all the keys corresponding to value `x`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only doing this once, use the list comprehension methods in the other answers.

If you are doing this multiple times, create a new dict that indexes keys by values:

```
from collections import dictdefault

def valueindex(d):
    nd = dictdefault(list)
    for k,v in d.iteritems():
        nd[v].append(k)
    return nd

parent_child = valueindex(childparent)
assert parent_child[0] == [1,2]
assert parent_child[1] == [3,4]
```